# Prove inequallity of number of steps in a simple random walk

Tags: random-walk

> Let $S_n$ be a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$, starting from 0, and let $c>0$ be an integer. Show that $$ \mathbb{P}\left(\underset{1\leq j\leq n}{\max}|S_{j}|\geq c\right)\leq2\mathbb{P}\left(|S_{n}|\geq c\right) $$

I am struggling with this one for a while, still not sure how to start. My first intuition is to use markov inequallity, but I cant see exactly how.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain the assumptions that go into a "simple random walk"?

Comment: @Michael $S_n$ is the sum of Rademacher i.i.d random variables.

Comment: The reflection principle applies

Comment: This is a standard result and can be found in any book which covers random walks… if you don’t want spoilers, tag me for a hint.

Comment: @AndrewZhang : It is not clear if symmetry applies or not. The OP has not responded.  A google search on "simple random walk" gives various definitions, some including symmetry, some not.  For your "Rademacher" description it also is not clear if symmetry holds.  I believe the result holds regardless but it is easier to prove under symmetry assumptions.

Comment: @Michael Symmetry applies.

Comment: @AndrewZhang can you point me to one?

Comment: @DirichletIsaPartyPooper Apparently I have misled you, since I also cannot find a reference covering this identical problem. But as jlammy said, if you google reflection principle simple random walk, you will find a lot of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Fix $n$ as a positive integer. Just look at the event $\{S_n\geq c\}$ for simplicity (the case $S_n\leq -c$ is similar).  Let $M$ be the first time index $i$ such that $S_i\geq c$ (define $M=\infty$ if it never happens). Then
$$\cup_{i=1}^n\{M=i, S_n\geq S_i\} \subseteq \{S_n\geq c\}$$
and notice by symmetry that
$$P[S_n\geq S_i|M=i]\geq 1/2 \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., n\} \quad (*)$$
Now you can prove that
$$P[\cup_{i=1}^n\{M=i\}] \leq 2P[S_n\geq c]$$

---

This symmetry argument works whenever we have the following general scenario: $S_0=0$ and
$$ S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_iV_i \quad \forall n \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$$
where $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ and $\{V_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are mutually independent processes, $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. random variables of any distribution (possibly noninteger), $\{V_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ are i.i.d. with $P[V_i=1]=P[V_i=-1]=1/2$. Then equation (*) applies.